# Invalid Codec Private Data Exception when viewing KVS produced by a custom Android Producer

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, hevc, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

We've implemented custom Android Producer, using examples as a reference point from:

- [AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp)
- [aws-sdk-android](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/tree/main) example, specifically examples for [ImageFileMediaSource](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/main/aws-android-sdk-kinesisvideo/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/kinesisvideo/mediasource/file/ImageFileMediaSource.java) and [ImageFileMediaSourceConfiguration](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/main/aws-android-sdk-kinesisvideo/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/kinesisvideo/mediasource/file/ImageFileMediaSourceConfiguration.java).

The implementation should work correctly as in the AWS console we can see that data is being streamed:
[image: Screenshot from 2023-05-22 09-12-30]

We're streaming H.265 encoded video stream and have found out the following CPD (Codec Private Data) in the stream:

```
00 00 00 01 40 01 0c 01 ff ff 01 40 00 00 03 00 
80 00 00 03 00 00 03 00 78 ac 0c 00 00 0f a0 00 
01 d4 c2 00 fa 28 00 00 00 01 42 01 01 01 40 00 
00 03 00 80 00 00 03 00 00 03 00 78 a0 03 c0 80 
10 e7 fa 2e ec 91 77 a2 5d 58 10 00 00 3e 80 00 
07 53 0c 40 00 00 00 01 44 01 c1 ad f0 13 64
```

It consists of Sequence Parameter Set (SPS), Picture Parameter Set (PPS) and Video Parameter Set (VPS) frames, each starting with start bytes `00 00 00 01`. As specified in the reference manual for [Stream Structures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-reference-structures-stream.html) we've used this data to specify the `final byte[] codecPrivateData` when creating a new `StreamInfo` object, which is created in our implementation of custom `MediaSource`, overridden in method `getStreamInfo`. Based on above data in the stream we've passed it in the following way:

```
new byte[]{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x40, 0x01, 0x0c, 0x01, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, 0x01, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, (byte) 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x78, (byte) 0xac, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, (byte) 0xa0, 0x00, 0x01, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0xc2, 0x00, (byte) 0xfa, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x42, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, (byte) 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x78, (byte) 0xa0, 0x03, (byte) 0xc0, (byte) 0x80, 0x10, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xfa, 0x2e, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x91, 0x77, (byte) 0xa2, 0x5d, 0x58, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3e, (byte) 0x80, 0x00, 0x07, 0x53, 0x0c, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x44, 0x01, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0xf0, 0x13, 0x64 },
```

Also we've specified flag `NAL_ADAPTATION_ANNEXB_CPD_AND_FRAME_NALS` as last parameter when creating `StreamInfo`. According to the following document about [NAL Adaptation Flags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-reference-nal.html) our stream is in Annex-B delimited format for NALUs, which means we need to use that flag.

But regardless of all that, we're still seeing the following error in [KVS media viewer](https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-media-viewer/):

```
"message": "Could not parse CPD in HEVC (H.265) format.",
"code": "InvalidCodecPrivateDataException",
```

I've prepared a 10s long video stream in H.265 [accessible here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PDwG5eEn1ris3FzIzhcHdpE6XJJAU47i/view?usp=sharing) if it helps debug this issue and to check that CPD is indeed correct.